# Composer.json location and linking to psr-4 namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I'm sure this is a really stupid question but I'm new to composer and I'm struggling with autoloading my classes.

My folder structure is like this

```
composer.json
models
->Beer.php //class for type of beer
controllers
views
public
tests
```

My autoload in my json is currently this:

```
"autoload" : {
        "psr-4": {
            "drinkr\\models": "models/Beers",
        }
    }
```

In my beers.php class I have

```
namespace Beer;

class Beers....
```

Can someone help me understand how to correctly connect the above?

Also should everything bar my composer.json file be in a /src folder and a /tests folder?

```
composer.json
src
tests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mistake is here

`"drinkr\\models": "models/Beers"`

and

`namespace Beer;`

rename file "beers.php" to "Beers.php" and change namespace to "Beers"

Comment: OK what I've done is rename my class file to Beer.php, my class to Beer. The code in my composer.json is now drinkr\\models\\": "models/Beer"
In my file I'm trying to load the class in I have $foo = new \Beers\Models\Beer();